# Why is R not scanning the data

Tags: r

I try to scan a data in R.
My Code:

```
scan("D:\\Projekt1\\Lauf.dat",sep=",")
```

The content of my data:

> 10.2, 11.4, 10.5, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 10.3, 10.8, 10.2, 11.5,
> 10.0, 11.4, 11.2, 10.1, 10.5, 12.0, 11.4, 10.2, 10.1, 12.1

Expected Output:

> [1] 10.2 11.4 10.5 9.8 9.9 9.9 10.3 10.8 10.2 11.5 10.0 11.4 11.2 10.1
> 10.5
>
> [16] 12.0 11.4 10.2 10.1 12.1

But I got this error:

> Warning in file(file, "r") : cannot open file '': Invalid argument
>
> Error in file(file, "r") (main.R#1): cannot open the connection Show
> stack trace

What did I wrong? I hope you can help me.

BR
Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```r
setwd("D:\\Projekt1") 
scan("Lauf.dat",sep=",")
```

#### edit-1:

`setwd("D:/Projekt1") #used forward slash`

Comment: With the code: `setwd("‪D:\\Projekt1")` i got this error: 
`(main.R#1): cannot change working directory
Show stack trace`

Comment: why are you having `\\\` in your path?

Comment: In R you must write the path with ´\\\`.
If I try to write it with ´\\` I got this Error: `Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""D:\P"´

Comment: Perfekt! Thank you